# how to test and benchmark aerospike

Tags: benchmarking, couchbase, aerospike

Am trying to do a benchmark of using aerospike, For example, lets say if I want to test storing a document may be JSON in aerospike and do the same test against couchbase, what kinda tool/method i can use it to test between aerospike and couchbase.

Comment: what did you try so far ?

Comment: am trying to do i via jmeter but no luck, since am a beginner, may take sometime i think.

Comment: So, which one is faster or you liked more (more secure, easier or more features)  Aerospike, Hyperdex or Couchbase ?
Regards

Answer (score 5):

I am not very familiar with Couchbase but can give you pointers to benchmark against Aerospike (I work there). YCSB (Yahoo! Cloud System Benchmark) would probably be the best tool to use against both. [Here is](https://github.com/aerospike/ycsb) the code to use against Aerospike.

Now for specifically benchmarking Aerospike, I would recommend using one of Aerospike's benchmark tools, for example the [Java benchmark tool](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/benchmarks.html) and use a String (-o S:) or a Java blob (-o B:) with a length comparable to your json document.

For example:

`./run_benchmarks -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3000 -n test -k 10000000 -b 1 -o B:1400 -w RU,80 -z 8`

This would run a workload of 80% reads and 20% writes (`-w RU,80`) and using 8 concurrent threads (`-z 8`).

Some important points to consider though:

- Ideally this should run against a 2+ node cluster (so you do check with replication factor 2).
- You would probably need more then 1 client host as you would likely hit bottlenecks on the client side before saturating the cluster.
- You would want to find out the optimal number of threads for your workload / object size. Typically between 60 and 100.

Finally, I would recommend reading some of the [published document](http://www.aerospike.com/benchmarks/) related to benchmarking Aerospike and other NoSQL databases. Particularly, [this one](http://www.aerospike.com/blog/aerospike-doubles-in-memory-nosql-database-performance/).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much Meher , it is useful I will work on it and update here about the result. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

For Couchbase the process is similar, with Couchbase offering a tool for generating an amount of traffic on a cluster, via [cbworkloadgen](http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbworkloadgen_tool.html).

A comparable workload to the one suggested by Aerospace above, would be executed as follows (while in the directory specified in the link above according to your OS):

`./cbworkloadgen -n 127.0.0.1:8091 -u username -p password -j -i 10000000 -r 0.2 -t 8`

As with Aerospike's example, 80:20 reads/writes (`-r 0.2`) and 8 concurrent threads (`-t 8`) again, with JSON documents (note, not JSON *blobs*) being stored (`-j`)

If you're benchmarking for a future use case, try to use a setup close to what you'll be using (i.e. multiple nodes of a hardware configuration close to what you intend to use), both in terms of the datastore cluster and the client hosts (i.e. multiple hosts).

Finally, lots of different companies will produce many different benchmarks that may or may not accurately represent the performance you can expect to get of their software (and how they claim it will behave in relation to competitors). It's important that you research thoroughly and match any claims to your own benchmarks. Some published benchmark may return performance of one level, while on your particular setup getting the same performance *may* be possible, but might require really minute tuning (and a large amount of effort on your part).

Comment: "may have been engineered" which is why you use a third-party tool, like YCSB, as Yahoo couldn't care less about Couchbase nor Aerospike.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to test Aerospike recently. What I use the benchmark is the [benchmark](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/tree/master/benchmarks) included in aerospike-client. It may be a good choice. :)